# Coding for a selected item in listView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, c++-cli

I have a list view `listView1` with `Details` veiw in my C++/CLI winform and I would like to execute a code depending on duable clicking on the current  selected item in `listView1`. How I can do such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the doubleclick event of the ListView and check what item was under the cursor (if any) like:

```
void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(Object^  sender, MouseEventArgs^  e) 
{
     ListViewItem^ item = this->listView1->GetItemAt(e->X, e->Y);
}
```

Comment: How can I declare the event `MouseDoubleClick` of the listView1 before I use it?

Comment: @Adban: Either you can use the Forms Designer to add an event handler, or you can do `listView1->MouseDoubleClick += gcnew MouseEventHandler(&MyForm::listView1_MouseDoubleClick, this);` any time after creating the listview, to hook up the event.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks it is working now, but How I can do that in Forms Designer!

Comment: @Adban: It depends on which version of Visual Studio you have.  Not all versions support designing Windows Forms in C++/CLI projects.  I usually go with C# for GUI and C++/CLI for backend processing and interfacing to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **ItemActivate** event (while **Activation** property is set to **ItemActivation.DoubleClick**). Then you can set up everything from designer.

You can check out [Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express), a free WinForms component with many aspects of the original ListView improved.